# Hashgraph diagram with 2-way communication when nodes gossip?

Tags: hashgraph

The hashgraph introductory paper ["The Hashgraph Protocol: Efficient Asynchronous BFT For High-Throughput Distributed Ledgers"](https://doi.org/10.1109/COINS49042.2020.9191430) (Baird, Luykx, 2020), has a diagram of the hashgraph data structure - Figure 1<sup>**†**</sup> - which is very similar to the one [on the Hedera site here](https://hedera.com/learning/hedera-hashgraph/what-is-hashgraph-consensus), and a part of the hashgraph, as diagramed there, looks similar to this abbreviated version:

[image]

The main issue is that these (typical) hashgraph diagrams do not, to my eyes, show the *two-way* gossip when nodes talk.

For example, at the top of this diagram, when the *middle* node `M` has just talked with the *left* node `L` to produce event `A` incorporating `L`'s state as of event `B`, node `M` already knows stuff from node `R`'s event `C` - but I don't see an event on node `L` showing that `L` now knows about `C`.  Which is what I would have expected for the two-way gossip when `M` spoke with `L`.  From the paper:

> *A. Gossip About Gossip: Communicating the Hashgraph*
>
> The hashgraph protocol uses gossip to communicate, as described
> in Algorithm 1. A node, Alice, chooses another node at random, say
> Bob, and then Alice sends Bob what she knows that he does not
> know, **and vice versa.** [emphasis added]

Is this what the the hashgraph *really* looks like?  If so, then what to make of the "and vice versa"; is the gossip *not* 2-way?  Alternatively, what *should* these diagrams look like?

---

<sup>**†**</sup> Copyrighted image not reproduced here for fear of violating fair use - but if an editor on this site knows better let me know and I'll copy it in and use it instead of mine.)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if L learnt of new information as a result of it's exchange with M, a new event would be created above B to commemorate it.

The drawing you shared would suggest that only M learnt something from L, however seeing M commemorated its conversation with C, it learnt something that L doesn't know and there should be another event in L's "lane" as a result.

Comment: So it _is_ a two-way exchange.  Hi Greg!

Comment: It is indeed, both nodes exchange what they don't know about each other's graph respectively.